# Multibinding and Validation

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF application which includes (UK) address information including the Postcode. For some reason the db stores the postcode in two parts, while the UI design calls for one textbox with both parts combined. I have a valueconverter which handles this operation in both directions. All fine so far. However, I'm now adding validation using IDataErrorInfo. I have added ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" in my xaml but the indexer on the object is never called.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8"  TabIndex="8" Margin="0,3"
                         Name="txtPostcode" 
                         PreviewTextInput="txtPostcode_PreviewTextInput" >
                    <TextBox.Text >
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myPostcodeConverter}" 
                                      ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                            <Binding Path="Client.AddressList/PostCode1" />
                            <Binding Path="Client.AddressList/PostCode2" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

If I add the ValidatesOnDataErrors to the individual bindings instead, then the indexer is called but I get strange run-time errors of the form "Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array" although these do not appear when I single-step through the code.
Furthermore, [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.validatesondataerrors(v=vs.100).aspx) seems to imply that "ValidatesOnDataErrors" should be applied to the MultiBinding, not the individual ones. Anyone done this?

OK [this question seems to be very close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052150/problem-with-validation-and-multibinding) to a duplicate, but the OP gave up - any progress in the last nearly 6 years?

Comment: I would recommend reading the WPF release notes and see if anything is mentioned, but it sounds like the bug hasn't been fixed. You might want to consider reporting it on Visual Studio User Voice (with tag "Windows Presentation Foundation"). http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/89380-windows-presentation-foundation